# Intermittent issue with Spring security @PreAuthorize annoation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I am currently working on Spring boot project which is acting as datasource for UI layer and all endpoint within project are protected using OIDC.

Everything is working as expected however when i try to protect any controller endpoint by putting `@PreAuthorize`  annotation it works well in local development environment (JDK 8) but when things gets deployed over cloud (PCF, OpenJDK) it having weird behavior as 8 out of 10 times it works and 2 times it allows user to bypass security at method level and get desired output.Not sure how to fix this, i am suspecting something do with AOP proxy here but not sure. 
Any pointer will be much appreciated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

}
```

Security config class for reference.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Value("${jwt-token.audience}")
  private String resourceId;

  @Value("${jwt-token.issuer-uri}")
  private String issuer;

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(resourceId).stateless(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder())
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter());
    // @formatter:on
  }

  @Bean
  JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {    
    //omitted for brevity    
    return jwtDecoder;
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
    return new RequestContextListener();
  }
}
```

Comment: How many clusters (instances) do you have?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad Thanks for swift response, currently we are having only one instance.

Comment: can you please  put your SecurityConfiguration into question?

Comment: One more question, where you put @PreAuthorize? on the controller endpoints? or on services(methods)?

Comment: Added the same!

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad Tried on service as well but same issue.

Comment: Please use .fullyAuthenticated() instead of  .authenticated() then test it

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad - Sure will give it a try but can you please help me understand why its having intermittent behavior ?

Comment: I think this might be related to caching mechanisms on clouds. (Considering that it works well on your local). I keep trying to solve this problem

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad - I tried .fullyAuthenticated() as well however that it didn't help either :(